# Python OpenCV Error in The IPython Notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

i have error for run this code in The IPython Notebook.
my code:

```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  # Create a black image
  img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
  # Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
  img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
  cv2.imshow('image',img)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
```

error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-dc7e5a608b64> in <module>()
      6 # Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
      7 img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
----> 8 cv2.imshow('image',img)
      9 cv2.waitKey(0)

error: ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reassign the `img` array with the output of `cv2.line` function, yet
according to the [reference](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) its output is `None`.

This version would give you the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```